# JSON giving null result

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to fetch data from my database which located on my web server.

I've uploaded my PHP file get_data.php on to the web server.

```
    <?php
define('HOST','localhost.000webhostapp.com');
define('USER','id1206871_myuser');
define('PASS','******');
define('DB','id1206871_mydb'); 
  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

  $sql = "select * from person";

  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result,
    array('id'=>$row[0],
    'name'=>$row[1],
    'address'=>$row[2]
  ));
}
$json_errors = array(
    JSON_ERROR_NONE => 'No error has occurred',
    JSON_ERROR_DEPTH => 'The maximum stack depth has been exceeded',
    JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR => 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded',
    JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX => 'Syntax error',
);

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

echo 'Last error : ', $json_errors[json_last_error()], PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

When I try this URL https://mrpcml.000webhostapp.com/get_data.php
I get

> {"result":null}Last error : No error has occurred

I've also tried to validate JSON.

> Error: Parse error on line 1: mrpcml.comli.com / g ^ Expecting
>   'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Why am I getting this *null*? Where is the problem?
I'm not sure about my db host.

Comment: var_dump() & echo are your friends..my friend!!

Answer (score 0):

Your $result variable was declared inside of the while loop (do it outside). Plus make sure you will initialise it as an array.

Comment: i'm new on php .. i don't know if i did what you said .. i changed the code to be as ..$result=array();
  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
   the result is :{"result":[]}

Comment: to push things into the php array inside of the loop, you will need something like this:
    $result[] = $row;